# Label generation in Antlr4 with C++ does not allow accessing the label value

Tags: c++, c++11, antlr, antlr4

I have an old grammar that I had working with some Java code, I'm changing the generation now in Cpp.

My rule contains a label but when I'm implementing the Listener upon exit rule, there is no way to get the value of the item by label in CPP

the rule is :

```
msg : 
    destination=address
    time
    sender=address
;
```

The way I was accessing the label value in Java (from My custom Listener) was was like this:

```
ctx.destination.getText()
```

but some how now in CPP I can see that in the generated base listener the destination label is used to generate a nullptr that is never used.

```
MessageGrammar::AddressContext *destination = nullptr;
```

I'm I doing something wrong? are the labels not used in the CPP generation ?

Comment: There is no way that `setDestinationAddress` ever worked for that grammar. The identifier `destinationAddress` doesn't even appear in the grammar and the Java target doesn't generate setters for labels either.

Comment: setDestinationAddess is in my own object. the ctx.destination was the way to access the label. I edited the test of the question

Answer (score 0):

That is what ANTLR4 generates for me:

```
ExampleParser::MsgContext* ExampleParser::msg() {
  MsgContext *_localctx = _tracker.createInstance<MsgContext>(_ctx, getState());
  enterRule(_localctx, 16, ExampleParser::RuleMsg);

  auto onExit = finally([=] {
    exitRule();
  });
  try {
    enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
    setState(60);
    dynamic_cast<MsgContext *>(_localctx)->destination = address();
    setState(61);
    time();
    setState(62);
    dynamic_cast<MsgContext *>(_localctx)->sender = address();

  }
  catch (RecognitionException &e) {
    _errHandler->reportError(this, e);
    _localctx->exception = std::current_exception();
    _errHandler->recover(this, _localctx->exception);
  }

  return _localctx;
}
```

As you can see the `destination` member gets the result from the `address` rule invocation assigned.

The `destination` member is public, so you can access it in your listener (on rule exit, not on rule enter, where this field is not assigned yet).

Comment: I think then I must have some issue with my generated classes, the destination for me is never used except for the init MessageGrammar::AddressContext *destination = nullptr;